# get the last value, second last value and the third last value by id and month

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL Workbench 6.3 . I have the following dataset.

```
id  date        value
36  12/1/2015   3174
36  11/1/2015   3143
36  10/1/2015   3112
36  9/1/2015    3082
36  8/1/2015    3052
36  7/1/2015    3021
36  6/1/2015    2990
64  11/1/2015   3105
64  10/1/2015   3074
64  8/1/2015    3014
64  7/1/2015    2983
64  6/1/2015    2952
65  12/1/2015   3414
72  10/1/2015   3352
72  9/1/2015    3322
72  8/1/2015    3292
72  7/1/2015    3261
72  6/1/2015    3230
72  5/1/2015    3198
72  4/1/2015    3169
72  3/1/2015    3139
72  2/1/2015    3107
72  1/1/2015    3079
```

What I am trying to get is group by id and get the last 3 month's value.
(keep all the date and value, if there is no records in the raw data.)
The following table is my manual output to show what I want to get. Thank you so much.

```
id  current_month   value1  1_month_before_current  value2  2_month_before_current  value3  3_month_before_current  value3
36  12/1/2015       3174    11/1/2015               3143    10/1/2015               3112    9/1/2015               3082
64  null            null    11/1/2015               3105    10/1/2015               3074    null                   null
72  null            null    null                    null    10/1/2015               3352    9/1/2015               3322
```

Comment: Which RDMS and/or Version?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 6.3

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when date = '2015-12-01' then date end) as current_month,
       max(case when date = '2015-12-01' then value end) as current_value,
       max(case when date = '2015-11-01' then date end) as prev_month,
       max(case when date = '2015-11-01' then value end) as prev_value,
       max(case when date = '2015-10-01' then date end) as prev2_month,
       max(case when date = '2015-10-01' then value end) as prev2_value,
from t
group by id;
```

If you don't like typing in the date:

```
select id,
       max(case when date = curmon then date end) as current_month,
       max(case when date = curmon then value end) as current_value,
       max(case when date = curmon - interval 1 month then date end) as prev_month,
       max(case when date = curmon - interval 1 month then value end) as prev_value,
       max(case when date = curmon - interval 2 month then date end) as prev2_month,
       max(case when date = curmon - interval 2 month then value end) as prev2_value,
from t cross join
     (select date('2015-12-01') as curmon) params
group by id;
```

Also, if the dates are not all on the first of the month, you can use range logic in the `case` expressions.

Comment: Could I know why use 'max' at here? And  I dont understand this line ' (select date('2015-12-01') as curmon) params'  what the meaning of params(temp table name?) and 'date('2015-12-01')' is means?

Comment: `params` is a basic derived table, a fundamental construct in SQL.  The `max()` is used just to choose the values that match the conditions.